# Using Environment Variables for Docker Distribution Middleware Configuration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, docker-registry

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/), you can configure a the docker registry image by either:

1. building a yaml file & mounting it.
2. Pass Environment Variables.

And the 2. approach says [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/):

> To override a configuration option, create an environment variable named REGISTRY_variable where variable is the name of the configuration option and the _ (underscore) represents indention levels. For example, you can configure the rootdirectory of the filesystem storage backend:
>
> ```
> storage:
>   filesystem:
>     rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
> ```
>
> To override this value, set an environment variable like this:
>
> ```
> REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/somewhere
> ```
>
> This variable overrides the /var/lib/registry value to the /somewhere directory.

Which works perfectly although there's one case where I cannot make it work, and that is Middleware config.

I want to pass by ENV vars this piece of setup

```
middleware:
  storage:
    - name: cloudfront
      options:
        baseurl: https://my.cloudfronted.domain.com/
        privatekey: /path/to/pem
        keypairid: cloudfrontkeypairid
        awsregion: us-east-1, use-east-2
```

I've tried passing the following env var names:

```
- REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_CLOUDFRONT_BASEURL
- REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_0_OPTIONS_BASEURL
```

but all of them seemed to be ignored, I've even tried to miswrite the config (as this will trigger a validation error and I'll be able to see it in the output), but no success.

I tried it with this:

```
# file.env
REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL="debug"
REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=":5000"
REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET="lol"

REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ENCRYPT=true
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ROOTDIRECTORY=/REG
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET="development-bucket-test"
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY="AAAAAAAA"
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY="BBBBBBB"
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION="XX-TTT-X"

REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_CLOUDFRONT_BASEURL="tp:/examplezzz.com"
REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_CLOUDFRONT_BASEUL="tp:/examplezzz.com"

REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_0_NAME=cloudfront
REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_0_OPTIONS_BASEUL="tp:/examplezzz.com"
REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE_0_OPTIONS__AWSRGION="tp:/examplezzz.com"
```

```sh
# run the registry with
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --env-file file.env registry:2.7.1 sh -c 'echo "version: 0.1" > /a.conf; registry serve /a.conf'
```

P.S.: The `/a.conf` is there to force an empty configuration

Am I missing something or is this setting only possible with config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and tinker with the sourcecode of the docker distribution by myself and made it accept the configs by passing:

```
REGISTRY_MIDDLEWARE_STORAGE="[{name: cloudfront, options: {baseurl: 'someurl', privatekey: 'somefile', keypairid: 'somestring'}}]"
```